# BigCommerce Category Name as a Filter in Handlebars

Tags: bigcommerce

My products have custom fields that I set up for the purpose of custom sorting. Some products belong to multiple categories so I create a custom field for each category that the product belongs to. I've been setting the Custom Field Name to the Category Name and the Custom Field Value to the sort order. Now I need to call the appropriate Name and Value onto the category page.

I've tried the following:

```
{{#filter custom_fields 'category.name' property='name'}}
{{#filter custom_fields category.name property='name'}}
{{#filter custom_fields '{{category.name}}' property='name'}}
{{#filter custom_fields {{category.name}} property='name'}}
```

Is it possible to use the category name as the custom field name filter? Can you please explain/show how to do this? TYIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is correct. However, since you are in the context of the product card (each category.products), the category context is lost. You would need to add a ../ (or 2) to go back up a level. For example: `{{#filter custom_fields ../category.name property='name'}}`.

This still may not work, however. I've run into issues in the past when working in a component and trying to get a parent's context. A simple way to ensure the variable gets passed down appropriately would be to specify it on the line that includes the card component. It will probably be found in the grid.html file, and will look something like: `{{>components/products/card settings=../settings show_compare=../show_compare show_rating=../settings.show_product_rating theme_settings=../theme_settings customer=../customer event=../event position=(add @index 1)}}`.

Simply add the category name here like so: `{{>components/products/card settings=../settings show_compare=../show_compare show_rating=../settings.show_product_rating theme_settings=../theme_settings customer=../customer event=../event position=(add @index 1) category_name=../category.name}}`.

Now, you can alter the original filter code to just use the new variable: `{{#filter custom_fields category_name property='name'}}`.